# Population Growth Word Problem Using the Law of Natural Growth

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The problem is included in the image below. There are three parts to the problem, and all three are on the same page. **I am looking for solution verification on all three parts**, but I have a specific question regarding part $c$.

If my answer is $t=2.5$ years, and the initial time is $2009$, is it correct to say that the answer is "in $2011$". I'm wondering because it is unclear in what month of $2009$ the population was recorded.

[image]

Comment: The part I can read says the growth rate is $0.9\%$ a year, There is no way the population will go to $439000$ in $4$ years.

Comment: Is the $0.9\%$ the instantaneous growth rate or the percentage growth in a year?

Comment: Whatever you did that produced the $0.15$ in $e^{0.15t}$ in the answer for part (a), make sure you don't do it again.

Comment: @DavidK Good advice- apparently I'm prone to pulling numbers out of thin air and trying to use them to solve problems. I have no idea where I got the $0.15$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.009y, y(0) = 241 \tag 1$$ where $t$ is the number years since $2009$ and $y$ is measured in the thousands.

$(1)$ has the solution $$y = 241e^{0.009t} \tag 2$$

for part (b) the population in $2013$ is $y(4) = 241e^{0.036}=243.834$

for part (c), set $350 = 241e^{0.009t}$ 
and solving for $t,$  we get $t = \frac{1}{0.009}\ln(350/241)=41.459$ in the year $2050.459,$  the population is estimated to be $350$ thousand.